# отсутсвует значение left_actions для toolbar

Tags: python, kivy

пробую написать приложение в Kivy на чистом Python'е без kv-файлов. когда запускаю этот код выдается ошибка 
[image: error]

```
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.toolbar import Toolbar

class StartScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **args):
    super().__init__(*arg, **args)
    self.orientation = 'vertical'
    toolbar = Toolbar(title = 'Welcome', left_action_items = [['red.png', lambda x: print('x')]])
    self.add_widget(toolbar)

class Program(App): 
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    title = "Application"
   def build(self): 
       return StartScreen()

Program().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.toolbar import Toolbar


class StartScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **args):
        super().__init__(*arg, **args)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        toolbar = Toolbar(title='Welcome')
        toolbar.left_action_items = [['menu', lambda x: print('x')]]
        self.add_widget(toolbar)
        self.add_widget(Widget())


class Program(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    title = "Application"

    def build(self):
        return StartScreen()


Program().run()
```

А вообще писать UI в Kivy на чистом Python - глупая затея! Вот так явно лучше:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
#: import Toolbar kivymd.toolbar.Toolbar


<StartScreen>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Toolbar:
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: x]]
        title: 'Basic Activity'

    Widget:
""")


class StartScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Program(App):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Blue'
    title = "Application"

    def build(self):
        return StartScreen()


Program().run()
```